# Can't understand this Javascript function (function overloading)

Tags: javascript, function, methods, overloading

I'm reading Secrets of Javascript Ninja and came across an example that I cannot fully understand. This same example was cited by some other user here before, but their doubts are different than mine. Here is the example:

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn) {

  var old = object[name];

  object[name] = function(){

       if (fn.length == arguments.length)

          return fn.apply(this, arguments)

       else if (typeof old == 'function')

          return old.apply(this, arguments);

    };
}
```

This is an example of function overloading, used this way:

```
var ninja = {};
addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(){ /* do something */ });
addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(a){ /* do something else */ });
addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(a,b){ /* yet something else */ });
```

I have a solid understanding of scope, closure and the use of apply(). My doubts are:

- fn.length will return the number of parameters defined in fn. Will arguments.length return the number of which arguments? The already existing function's?
- But if so, and they match, why will it then apply the NEW function and not the existing one?
- If arguments.length returns the number of the given function, then when will they be different?
- I add 10 methods, starting with no parameters and increasing the number of them each time, after adding the 10th method, I call the method with no parameters, where did it 'store' the first function?
- I don't understand the use of ***old*** here.

I probably do not have some key concept that responds to all of the questions. Feel free to give me an explanation rather than responding the questions individually.

Comment: 1. `arguments.length` will be the # of args passed to the closest outer function from where it's called. 2. it will apply the one with the same call signature as the method(s) you added, or else go to the last one added. 3. `arguments.length` returns what's passed, not what's defined. 4. as old, which every methods uses closure to see. basically, it will start at the one for 10 args, and if there's not 10, then try 9, and if not 9, then try 8, all the way back to the one whose formal params matches the arguments.

Comment: incidentally, this is a very slow and ram-hungry way to setup variadic methods. if at all possible, the arity branches should all be defined in one function, using something like `switch(arguments.length)` to handle the routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `fn.length` will return the number of parameters defined in fn. Will `arguments.length` return the number of which arguments? The already existing function's?

No. `arguments` is an array-like local variable that's available inside of a function. It contains the number of arguments passed to the function.

The rest of your questions can answered by addressing this question:

> I add 10 methods, starting with no parameters and increasing the number of them each time, after adding the 10th method, I call the method with no parameters, where did it 'store' the first function?

Looking at the `addMethod` method one step at a time might be helpful:

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn) {

  var old = object[name];
  // Get the old function corresponding to this name. Will be "undefined"
  // the first time "addMethod" is called.


  object[name] = function(){
  // Now, assign object[name] to a new function.
  // The critical part of this function is that "old" is captured inside of
  // this function and will be available any time the function is called.

       if (fn.length == arguments.length)
       // if the number of parameters belonging to the function we've added
       // matches what was passed in, call "fn"
          return fn.apply(this, arguments)

       else if (typeof old == 'function')
       // Otherwise if there's another function with this name
       // call it instead.
          return old.apply(this, arguments);

    };
}
```

So lets take each call to `addMethod` in your example and examine the values of `fn` and `old`. You can think of the way that this is organized as functions stacked on top of each other, leveraging the scope of `old`.

```
addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(){ /* do something */ });
// old === undefined

addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(a){ /* do something else */ });
// old === function #1

addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(a,b){ /* yet something else */ });
// old === function #2
```

At the end of calling `addMethod` three times `ninja.whatever` refers to a function that calls function #3 if possible, and then calls the `old` function (function #2) if the arguments don't match function #3's parameter list length.

So visually, you can think of it like this:

```
function #3 (a,b)
function #2 (a)
function #1 ()
```

Where each function's `old` reference points to the function underneath it.

Now let's examine what happens when you call `ninja.whatever()`. This function is at the "bottom" of our stack.

1. The function currently associated with `whatever` is function #3. When calling function #3, `fn.length != arguments.length`, and so `old` (function #2) is executed.
2. So now we're executing function #2. Again, when calling function #2, `fn.length != arguments.length`, and `old` (function #1) is executed.
3. Finally, function #1 is executed. This time `fn.length == arguments.length` and so the function is called.

Comment: It gets more clear now. The cascade-closure scheme is the key concept I was missing. Thank you for the detailed question it was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Comments added:

```
//replace object[name] with a wrapper that either calls the passed-in 
//function (fn) or the old value of object[name]
function addMethod(object, name, fn) {

  //store object[name]    
  var old = object[name];



  object[name] = function(){

        //if the wrapper is called with as many arguments as is the arity of the passed in function (fn), call the passed in function (fn)
       if (fn.length == arguments.length)

          return fn.apply(this, arguments)

       //otherwise call the old value of object[name] but only if it is a function
       else if (typeof old == 'function')

          return old.apply(this, arguments);

    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a function is created it retains access to variables in the scope where it's defined.  In this case every method we create has access a scope with variables old, object, name, and fn.  The old variable is accessible from each method we add and the reference to it from the main object is overwritten so it's only accessible from "old" in that scope. You basically have a bunch of "old" variables are cascade through them to find the one that handles the number of arguments given.

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn) {

  // Get a reference to the existing method name.
  var old = object[name];

  /*
    Write over the method name with a new method
    that checks for a specific argument length.
    If the method is called with a different
    argument length and "old" exists call the
    old method.
  */

  object[name] = function(){

       if (fn.length == arguments.length)

          return fn.apply(this, arguments)

       else if (typeof old == 'function')

          return old.apply(this, arguments);

    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`function.length` is the number of arguments a function expects, the formal parameters. `arguments.length` is the actual number of arguments passed to the function, and that means the already existing function, because no arguments could have been passed to the new function; it wasn't called and is just a value. The `arguments` object is an array-like object containing the passed arguments. (the length property might make more sense knowing this). The difference between the length of given arguments and formal parameters is that a function can be passed more or less arguments than stated parameters. `console.log()` accepts any number of arguments, for example. Some of these functions just wrap a loop around the arguments object and to do something with each element in the arguments object. Each method added is stored as a property of the object given as the first parameter to the `addMethod` function. The variable `old` is just a variable, and names are not necessary to understand concepts. Perhaps the author was implying the mutability of objects and their properties by `old` (mutability is the ability to give a property a new value/ modify the object after its declaration).

Answer (score 0):

Most of your first questions are addressed by dandavis' comments. `arguments.length` gives the number of arguments applied to the function declared in the line

```
object[name] = function(){
```

The method is 'stored' in the `ninja` object declared in your first line of code and passed into subsequent calls.